# Is using web platform currency considered gambling?

Tags: gambling, online

Working on a web startup in which users receive platform currency by watching content. Later they can bid on spots in the site to post their own content, but only one out of all bidders gets the spot. Now here is the trick: the winner is determined randomly and the only proportional influence is the amount he bid (basically the more the better chances). Since **gambling** is determined by these 3 properties:

- chance
- consideration (paying something to play)
- a prize

Does my project fall into these? Especially since the platform currency has **no value outside of the platform**, same for the prize. And there is no possibility to **convert it to anything else** or **buy it**. Don't want to cross no no-no lines.

I couldn't find a similar example on the web (closest being zynga poker which is somehow not gambling). So maybe some of you have encountered a similar situation and know the answer?

Comment: This is a situation where all nuances matter, and you haven't even specified a jurisdiction. You need specific legal advice for your specific situation, this is not the place for that, you need to consult with a local lawyer.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, was thinking that my case is very specific... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### By your definition, it’s gambling

- chance: you said prizes are drawn at random
- consideration (paying something to play): eyeballs on a screen is something of value
- a prize: advertising is something of value being offered as a prize

Whether it’s *illegal* gambling depends on local law.